# Bulk add ttl column to dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, emr, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline, data-pipeline

I have a use case where I need to add ttl column to the existing table. Currently, this table has more than 2 billion records.

Is there any existing solution build around same? Or Should be emr is the path forward?

Answer (score 5):

DynamoDB does not support update operations that span primary key boundary. And for reading data, the only operation that spans partition boundaries is a Scan.

So, unfortunately the only way to add an attribute (DynamoDB is a document database, so there is no such concept as columns) to all items in a table is to actually execute a Put for each item.

If your table has about 2 billion items in it that will be 2 billion writes.

Of course, you can use EMR with Hive to connect to the table and execute a SQL-style update to add the TTL attribute but it will still translate into 2 billion individual PutItem requests so it will either take a while or be quite costly to run.

If the reason you would like to add the TTL is because you are trying to delete a significant number of the items in the table, perhaps a better aproach would be to creat a new table, copy the records you need there with TTl and all, and then delete the old table.

Answer (score 1):

It is not directly supported, but you are in luck that [this AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/backfilling-an-amazon-dynamodb-time-to-live-ttl-attribute-with-amazon-emr/) was recently published that covers the process in depth.